# Central Limit Theorem with $\sqrt{S_{n}}$

Tags: probability-theory, central-limit-theorem, law-of-large-numbers

Let $X_{1}, X_{2}, \ldots$ be i.i.d. with $X_{i} \geq 0, E X_{i}=1, \operatorname{Var} X_{i}=1.$ Roughly, by the central
limit theorem we might expect that
$2(\sqrt{S_{n}}-\sqrt{n})=\int_{n}^{S_{n}} \frac{d x}{x^{1 / 2}} \approx \frac{S_{n}-n}{\sqrt{n}} \Rightarrow Z$
with $Z \sim N(0,1)$
Give a complete proof that $2 (\sqrt{S_{n}}-\sqrt{n}) \Rightarrow Z$

$S_n = X_1+X_2+...+X_n$.

I am not sure how to deal with the $\sqrt{S_{n}}$. I cannot even compute the characteristic function. Any hint will be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: The idea is more or less correct except you messed up some factors of $\sigma$. See my answer for details, in a method that does not require integration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write

$$ 2(\sqrt{S_n} - \sqrt{n}) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{S_n/n} + 1} \cdot \frac{ S_n - n}{\sqrt{n}} $$

and note that

- $S_n/n \to \mathbb{E}[X_1] = 1$ in distribution by either version of LLN.
- $(S_n - n)/\sqrt{n} \to \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$ in distribution by CLT.

So by the converging together lemma (a.k.a. Slutsky's Theorem), it follows that

$$ 2(\sqrt{S_n} - \sqrt{n}) \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{\text{law}} \frac{2}{\sqrt{1} + 1} \cdot \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2) = \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2). $$

Answer (score 1):

Let $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ denote a normal random variable of mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. We can proceed by using Taylor's theorem and the strong law of large numbers (SLLN). By the SLLN, there is an event $E$ with $\mathbf P(E) = 1$ such that $(S_n-n)/n\longrightarrow 0$ on $E$. On $E$ we write:
\begin{align*}
2(\sqrt{S_n} - \sqrt n) &= 2(\sqrt{n + S_n-n} - \sqrt{n})\\
&= 2\sqrt{n}\bigg(\sqrt{1+\frac{S_n-n}{n}}-1\bigg)\\
&= 2\sqrt{n}\bigg(1 + \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{S_n-n}{n} + O\bigg(\frac{S_n-n}{n}\bigg)^2 - 1\bigg) \\
&= \frac{S_n-n}{\sqrt n} + \sqrt{n}\cdot O\bigg(\frac{S_n-n}{n}\bigg)^2 \\
&= \frac{S_n-n}{\sqrt n} + O\bigg(\frac{S_n-n}{n^{3/4}}\bigg)^2.
\end{align*}
By Theorem 2.5.11 of Durrett's *Probability Theory and Examples, 5th ed.*,
$$
\frac{S_n-n}{n^{3/4}} \longrightarrow 0 \quad\text{a.s.}
$$
Convergence a.s. implies convergence in distribution. Since $X_i-1$ has mean $0$ and variance $\sigma^2$ and $0$ is a constant, we apply the converging together lemma to conclude that
$$
2(\sqrt{S_n}-\sqrt n) \Rightarrow N(0,\sigma^2) + 0 = \sigma N(0,1),
$$
as desired.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't write it but I am assuming you mean that $S_n=X_1+\cdots +X_n$ (some people use other conventions, for instance the [the wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) uses a different convention than yours).

Applying the central limit theorem yields that
$$
\frac{S_n-n}{\sqrt{n}}
$$
converges in law to Gaussian random variable with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma^2$, let's call such a random variable $G$ to avoid conflicting notation with your $Z$.

Rearranging the convergence, we can equivalently say that $S_n=n+\sqrt{n}G+o(\sqrt{n})$, using the asymptotic notation $o(f(n))$ to denote a (potentially random) quantity whose limit as $n\to\infty$ when divided by $f(n)$ equals $0$.

Equivalently
$$
\frac{S_n}{n}=1+\frac{G}{\sqrt{n}}+o(n^{-1/2}),
$$
so we can take the square root of both sides (using the [fractional binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)) to conclude that
$$
\frac{\sqrt{S_n}}{\sqrt n}=1+\frac{G}{2\sqrt{n}}+o(n^{-1/2}).
$$
Multiplying through by $\sqrt{n}$ and rearranging yields the result that
$
\sqrt{S_n}-\sqrt{n}
$
converges in law to $G/2$, i.e. to a Gaussian random variable with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma^2/4$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $S_n':=S_n/n$. Then $\sqrt{n}(S_n'-1)\xrightarrow{d}\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$. Applying the [delta method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method),
$$
\sqrt{S_n}-\sqrt{n}=\sqrt{n}\!\left(\sqrt{S_n'}-1\right)\xrightarrow{d}\mathcal{N}\!\left(0,\sigma^2/(2\sqrt{1})^2\right).
$$