# Limiting Distributions and expectation of sequence of RVs

Tags: probability, random-variables, probability-limit-theorems

We're given a sequence $X_i$ of i.i.d non-negative random variables, with $\mu = 4$ and $\sigma^2 = 16$.
We're asked to calculate:
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} E[cos (\sqrt{S_n} - 2\sqrt{n})],$$ where $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$.

I have no clue where to start. Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, note that
$$
\sqrt{n}(S_n/n-\mu)\xrightarrow{d}\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2),
$$
and, [therefore](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3440222/central-limit-theorem-with-sqrts-n),
$$
\sqrt{S_n}-\sqrt{\mu n}=\sqrt{n}\left(\sqrt{S_n/n}-\sqrt{\mu}\right)\xrightarrow{d}\mathcal{N}\!\left(0,\sigma^2/(2\sqrt{\mu})^2\right)\overset{d}{=}N.
$$
Thus, since $x\mapsto\cos(x)$ is [bounded and continuous](http://theanalysisofdata.com/probability/8_5.html),
$$
\mathsf{E}\cos(\sqrt{S_n}-\sqrt{\mu n})\to \mathsf{E}\cos(N).
$$

> The answer is $e^{-1/2}$.

Answer (score 0):

alternative procedure.

$$\frac{\left(\sqrt{S_n}-2\sqrt{n}\right)\cdot\left(\sqrt{S_n}+2\sqrt{n}\right))}{4\sqrt{n}}=\frac{S_n-4n}{4\sqrt{n}}$$

that is

$$\left(\sqrt{S_n}-2\sqrt{n}\right)=\frac{4\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{S_n}+2\sqrt{n}}\cdot\frac{S_n-4n}{4\sqrt{n}}=\frac{4}{\sqrt{\overline{X}_n}+2}\cdot\frac{S_n-4n}{4\sqrt{n}}=A\cdot B$$

Now:

$$A\xrightarrow{\mathcal{P}}1$$

$$B\xrightarrow{d}N(0;1)$$

thus using Slutsky Theorem you have that

$$A\cdot B\xrightarrow{d}N(0;1)$$